# How to change password in Admin

Tags: impresspages

When I create another admin user, how can he change password. I disallow 'Administrators' permissions since he can make him self SuperAdmin. Without that he cannot change his profile, like password. Is there a way to have better control on Administrators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use password reminder option from a login screen. There's no "user profile" functionality for each administrator separately.